# Youtube ?rel=0 tag no longer working

Tags: youtube

I was trying to share a Youtube link and wanted the person to just see that clip without any of the irrelevant suggestions that pop up next to it. I knew that adding `?rel=0` (or `&rel=0`) at the end of the URL used to achieve this, but this doesn't seem to be working anymore. After googling a bit, I found suggestions to use the youtu.be domain instead of youtube.com, but suggestions were shown nonetheless, or the URL gave an error. How else can I share this link and have no 'related' clips shown on the side? Thanks!

Comment: Starting sep 18 it no longer fully works, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48386252/youtube-iframe-api-parameter-rel-0-doesnt-work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rel=0` is used to disable related videos shown at the end of a video, not to remove the suggested videos in the sidebars.

You can use the embed URL to access the video on it's own - http://youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ. Add `?rel=0` to disable the related videos at the end too.

Answer (score 4):

Note, that `rel=0` no longer works if you are signed into your Google account (YouTube, Gmail, etc).

`&rel=0` only works when not signed in. However, you can get around this by using the enhanced privacy mode:

`https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/[id]?rel=0`

Comment: Even with the nocookie domain it no longer works, it does show only related videos from your channel with rel=0

Comment: It works only if you have published it on a channel which does not have any other video's else you will still see other videos from the channel at the end. You can test it for yourself for example: https://jsfiddle.net/07ow4x6c/

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Then neither this, or the suggested answer actually work then?

Comment: Yes it doesn't work unless you don't have any other videos on the channel then it work's fine and that is only until google decides to change it again ;)
I believe vimeo has custom ending settings but it requires a paid subscription.

Answer (score 1):

As of [August 23, 2018](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#august-23,-2018),

> - The behavior for the `rel` parameter is changing on or after September
>   25, 2018. The effect of the change is that **you will not be able to
>   disable related videos**. However, you will have the option of
>   specifying that the related videos shown in the player should be from
>   the same channel as the video that was just played.
>
> To be more specific:
>
> - *Prior to the change*, if the parameter's value is set to 0, then the player does not show related videos.
> - *After the change*, **if** the `rel` parameter is **set to 0**, the player **will show related videos that are from the same channel** as the video that was **just** played.