# youtube iframe api parameter rel=0 doesn't work

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I need to hide related videos after watching the video. I set `rel=0`, but it is not working. I am using [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo?hl=ru) for testing. The `rel` checkbox value doesn't affect on shown related videos after watching video.

It doesn't work in google chrome. In mozilla firefox it properly works.

Answer (score 15):

As of September 25, 2018, you are not be able to disable related videos. Instead, if the rel parameter is set to 0, related videos will come from the same channel as the video that was just played.
[YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#showinfo)

Comment: Appears it is "changing" to only control whether related videos are from the same site or not. Weird.

Comment: @caneta I've given the link on YouTube API in my answer.

Comment: Sorry @IrinaKovalchuk, my Chrome browser took my italian locale and automatically show me the italian page which is not updated...forcing the browser to english (chrome://settings/languages), I could see the updated documentation and the sentence "Note: This parameter is deprecated and will be ignored after September 25, 2018." showed up.

Answer (score 8):

YouTube [changed the `rel=0` parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018) as of September 2018 so that it no longer fully disables related videos.

**However, you can work around this using the YouTube Player API to show custom HTML instead of related videos**.

Here is some example code that displays a custom "replay" button over the video once it completes, hiding the related videos:

```
<style>
    #playerWrap {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }
    #playerWrap.shown::after {
        content:"";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: black;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center; 
        background-size: 64px 64px;
        background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMjgiIGhlaWdodD0iMTI4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNTEwIDUxMCI+PHBhdGggZD0iTTI1NSAxMDJWMEwxMjcuNSAxMjcuNSAyNTUgMjU1VjE1M2M4NC4xNSAwIDE1MyA2OC44NSAxNTMgMTUzcy02OC44NSAxNTMtMTUzIDE1My0xNTMtNjguODUtMTUzLTE1M0g1MWMwIDExMi4yIDkxLjggMjA0IDIwNCAyMDRzMjA0LTkxLjggMjA0LTIwNC05MS44LTIwNC0yMDQtMjA0eiIgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==);
    }
</style>
<div>
    <div id="playerWrap">
        <iframe
            width="640" height="360"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0sDg2h3M1RE?enablejsapi=1"
            frameborder="0"
        ></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
  var playerFrame = document.currentScript.previousElementSibling.children[0].children[0];

  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player(playerFrame, {
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        document.getElementById("playerWrap").classList.add("shown");
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("playerWrap").addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.seekTo(0);
    document.getElementById("playerWrap").classList.remove("shown");
  });
</script>
```

For the minified code along with further description, details and instructions, [view my blog post on the subject](https://www.maxlaumeister.com/blog/hide-related-videos-in-youtube-embeds/).

Comment: I've found that Google Tag Manager causes this solution to fail.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you are most likely signed in on your Chrome browser, but not your Firefox browser.

`&rel=0` only works when not signed in. However, you can get around this by using the enhanced privacy mode:

`https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/[id]?rel=0`

Comment: should it be `youtube--nocookie.com` or `youtube-nocookie.com` ? the former does not work for me.

Comment: I am unable to get this to work with enhanced privacy mode:
https://codepen.io/iamrobert/pen/qJeVwN

Comment: Works for me, codepen looks good, no related videos offered at end of play sequence. Chrome and signed in to google/youtube. Change the domain back to youtube.com in codepen and related videos are shown.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to hide related video then you should call "player.stopVideo()" when player state is ended "PlayerState.ENDED".

PS: Sorry, english is not my first language.

Comment: This is a nice simple solution!

Comment: Not work. It END and show related video, you can't stop after END

Comment: Vitalicus, Did you tried to call stopVideo() when is playing?

Answer (score 1):

Here i found a Solution. stopVideo on player state changed to ENDING

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Alternative to hide Related Video & Info</title>
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="playerWrapOuter">
    <div id="playerWrap">
        <?php 
            $embed = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HjxYvcdpVnU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
            preg_match('/src="(.+?)"/', $embed, $matches);
            $src = $matches[1];
            $params = array(
                'width'          => "640",
                'height'         => "360",
                'enablejsapi'    => 1,
                'rel'            => 0,
                'modestbranding' => 1,
                'showinfo'       => 0,
            );


            $querystring  = http_build_query($params, $src);
            $new_src = $src.'?'. $querystring;
            $embed = str_replace($src, $new_src, $embed);
            $embed = str_replace( '<iframe ', '<iframe ', $embed );

            echo $embed; 
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    (function() {
        var player;
        var playerFrame = document.currentScript.previousElementSibling.querySelector("iframe");

        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
            player = new YT.Player(playerFrame, {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        };
        window.onPlayerStateChange = function(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                player.stopVideo();
            }
        };

    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Aishan/znabhuo2/
Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Irina Kovalchuk above, as of September 25, 2018, you are not be able to disable related videos.

But I found a workaround:

```
setInterval(function () {
    if (player.getCurrentTime() >= player.getDuration()-1) {
        player.seekTo(1);  
    }
}, 100);
```

as soon as video reaches to end move seek pointer to start. It won't give time to show related videos. *This workaround is suitable if you want to play video in loop*

Answer (score 0):

Mine wasn't working because the code spit out from the dev page https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

was incomplete and missing the closing tag!

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Checked this both with Chrome and Opera, it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/o8ztczn6/

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6UVZpQ8cLSQ?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

No related video is shown on finishing.

Comment: I've just check it in google chrome (Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and related videos are shown. Take a look at the screenshot  https://image.prntscr.com/image/5OPze6ZxTeyKAHGFiLXrcw.png

Comment: @Viktor Here is what I got with Google Chrome  https://imgur.com/a/Zjftx. Play finished, Google Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) Exactly the same as yours.

Comment: I noticed that related videos are shown when i'm signed in YouTube account. So rel=0 doesn't work for google chrome and mozilla firefox when i'm signed in. If I signed out no related videos is shown on finishing. So another question. How i can hide related videos for signed in users.